# Evaluating an exponential integral

Tags: integration

I am having troubles evaluating the following integral. The question suggest that I try reversing the order of integration: $\int_0^{1} \int_{9y}^{9} e^{x^2} \,dx\,dy$.

Is the strategy here to use some form of $u$-substitution? I am lost.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes you are right. You need to change the order of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Reversing the order of integration is the way to go:

$$\int_0^1 \int_{9y}^9 e^{x^2}\, dx \, dy = \int_0^9 \int_0^{x/9} e^{x^2}\, dy\, dx = \int_0^9 \frac{x}{9}e^{x^2}\, dx = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: After reversion of the order of integration you have function $ye^{y^2}$ with known antiderivative.